# Change contact picture programmatically

Tags: java, android, image, contacts

I have a picture, that is stored into the android phone. I want to be able to change the picture of a contact.

What I've done so far is launch the contact picker, have the user select a contact, and then I get the URI of the selected contact. From this contact, I can get the associated rawContact and I use [this code](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContacts.DisplayPhoto.html).

```
Uri rawContactPhotoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
             ContentUris.withAppendedId(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, rawContactId),
             RawContacts.DisplayPhoto.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
     try {
         AssetFileDescriptor fd =
             getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(rawContactPhotoUri, "rw");
         OutputStream os = fd.createOutputStream();
         os.write(photo);
         os.close();
         fd.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
         // Handle error cases.
     }
```

The problem is, the AssetFIleDescriptor is always empty (when I call length on it, we always get -1).

I'm not asking for the entire solution, just some leads to follow that can help me to get that working. I cannot seem to find this problem already on StackOverflow, so any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

It's always when we ask for question that we find the solution.
I want to share it for other

So I gave up on android link and find another one :
http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/programatically-adding-contacts-with-photo-using-contacts-provider-in-android-example/

The picture picker return the Uri of the selected contact, so with this you can get the Contact._ID of it :

```
// This is onActivityResult
final Uri uri = data.getData();
final Cursor cursor1 = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
final long contactId = cursor1.getLong(cursor1.getColumnIndex(Contacts._ID);
cursor1.close();
```

Then I had to get the RawContactId :

```
final Cursor cursor2 = getContentResolver().query(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, null,     RawContacts.Contact_ID + "=?", new String[] {String.valueOf(contactId)}, null);
cursor2.moveToFirst();
final long rawContactId = cursor2.getLong(cursor2.getColumnIndex(RawContacts._ID));
cursor2.close();
```

Then I had to get the Data._ID of the RawContacts (same way as above).

Then I used the ContentProviderOperations :

```
final ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI)
    .withSelection(Data._ID, dataId),
    .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO, byteArrayOfThePicture);

getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
```

And this is working like charm. Hope it helps

Comment: What permissions do you have in your AndroidManifest.xml? The contact picker provides a temporary READ permission on the URI retrieved, but you need to set the WRITE_CONTACTS permission in order to actually update a contact.

Comment: I have both READ and WRITE_CONTACT permission.

Answer (score 3):

```
String contactId = "10001"; // change it as your IDs
if (mBitmap != null) {
    // Picture
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream image = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, image);

        Uri rawContactUri = null;
        Cursor rawContactCursor = managedQuery(
            ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] {
                ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID
            },
            ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId,
            null,
            null);
        if (!rawContactCursor.isAfterLast()) {
            rawContactCursor.moveToFirst();
            rawContactUri = ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendPath("" + rawContactCursor.getLong(0)).build();
        }
        rawContactCursor.close();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        int photoRow = -1;
        String where111 = ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + " == " +
            ContentUris.parseId(rawContactUri) + " AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=='" +
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'";
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(
            ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
            null,
            where111,
            null,
            null);
        int idIdx = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Data._ID);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            photoRow = cursor.getInt(idIdx);
        }

        cursor.close();


        values.put(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID,
            ContentUris.parseId(rawContactUri));
        values.put(ContactsContract.Data.IS_SUPER_PRIMARY, 1);
        values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO, image.toByteArray());
        values.put(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
        if (photoRow >= 0) {
            getContentResolver().update(
                ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                values,
                ContactsContract.Data._ID + " = " + photoRow, null);
        } else {
            getContentResolver().insert(
                ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                values);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("!_@@Image_Exception", e + "");
    }
}
try {
    getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("@@@@@UPLOADERR", e + "");
}
```