# how to change contact picture progmatically which contact i select.?

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, android-listview, android-sqlite

i have no idea for that. but i want this program for my project.? plese help me.

thanx in Advance

Answer (score 3):

you can apply the new image using the following code inside any `Button`'s `onClickListener()` or inside `onActivityResult()` to apply :

```
final ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI)
    .withSelection(Data._ID, dataId),
    .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE),
    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO, byteArrayOfThePicture);

getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
```

make sure you have the required permissions first in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17789256/change-contact-picture-programmatically) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7974520/3193867) can be helpful.

Comment: i m new in android. in which place i can write this code? how can i use this code?

Comment: so this is write on my ActivityResult ??

Comment: i dont get your answer sir ? please suggest me some simple trick @SMR

Comment: @Hiteshpatel it is explained in his answer. you can use it any where you like but you need the `Contact Raw ID` first

Comment: chek this. @user3295685